# Cannot modify gmail thread category using gmail script API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, categories

Google scripts gmail api appears to provide no means to change the "category" label for a thread.

For normal labels the following thread & label methods are provided

```
GmailThread.addLabel(label)
GmailThread.getLabels()
GmailThread.removeLabel(label)

Label.getThreads()
Label.addToThread(thread)
Label.addToThreads(thread[])
Label.removeFromThread(thread)
Label.removeFromThreads(thread[])
```

I'm aware of the workaround to use the GmailApp.search(query) method to get threads based on category designation ("updates", "social", "promotions", "forums") but I can find no functionality which allows me to modify the category associated with a thread.

i.e. I cannot select certain threads marked as "social" and either remove the category designation or, for example change it to "forums".

Is there a workaround for this (c.f. search workaround referred to above).

Ultimately I think it would be useful to have additional methods similar to ones above for labels or to include categories within the existing labels class (i.e. currently GmailThread.getLabels() does not return the catogories)

thx

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature isn't built-in to Apps Script, but you can [file a feature request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#features) to have it added. I'm not aware of any workarounds.